# Embeded hazlecast spring boot connecting to itself error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I have a  reactive spring boot 3.0.2 application using embeded hazelcast 5.1.5.

This is my config file for embeded hazelcast:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelCastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HazelcastInstance.class)
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("baam-auth-connector");
        config.setClusterName("baam-auth-connector");

        return config;
    }
    
}
```

when I run my app it starts up successfully and my web services which use hazelcast work file, but after some minutes I see this warning in my logs:

```
2023-06-14T14:57:55.757+03:30  WARN 31976 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.i.s.tcp.TcpServerConnectionManager   : [192.168.53.176]:5701 [baam-auth-connector] [5.1.5] Packet send task is rejected. Target is this node! Target[uuid=c400aaee-521f-4f50-8fcc-31af7233002b, address=[127.0.0.1]:5701]
2023-06-14T14:57:55.758+03:30  WARN 31976 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OutboundResponseHandler   : [192.168.53.176]:5701 [baam-auth-connector] [5.1.5] Cannot send response: null to [127.0.0.1]:5701. com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp{serviceName='hz:core:clusterService', identityHash=305674867, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=75, invocationTime=1686742075780 (2023-06-14 14:57:55.780), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.tenantcontrol.NoopTenantControl@0}
2023-06-14T14:59:35.838+03:30  WARN 31976 --- [cached.thread-3] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner       : [192.168.53.176]:5701 [baam-auth-connector] [5.1.5] Connecting to self! [127.0.0.1]:5701

java.lang.RuntimeException: Connecting to self! [127.0.0.1]:5701
    at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerContext.shouldConnectTo(TcpServerContext.java:223) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnector.asyncConnect(TcpServerConnector.java:77) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnectionManager.lambda$getOrConnect$1(TcpServerConnectionManager.java:160) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnectionManagerBase$Plane.addConnectionInProgressIfAbsent(TcpServerConnectionManagerBase.java:206) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnectionManager.getOrConnect(TcpServerConnectionManager.java:158) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.server.ServerConnectionManager.getOrConnect(ServerConnectionManager.java:198) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.sendSplitBrainJoinMessage(AbstractJoiner.java:244) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.sendSplitBrainJoinMessageAndCheckResponse(AbstractJoiner.java:232) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:129) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:75) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:42) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:77) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) ~[hazelcast-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
```

Also I tried this config, but I get another warning similar to the first one:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelCastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HazelcastInstance.class)
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig());
    }


    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setClusterName("baam-auth-connector");
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setMulticastGroup("224.2.2.4")
                .setMulticastPort(54328);

        return config;
    }
```

```
2023-06-14T15:13:55.774+03:30  WARN 33633 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.i.s.tcp.TcpServerConnectionManager   : [192.168.53.176]:5701 [baam-auth-connector] [5.1.5] Packet send task is rejected. Target is this node! Target[uuid=e4b99875-5a82-43f4-9a59-639f527cd596, address=[127.0.0.1]:5701]
2023-06-14T15:13:55.776+03:30  WARN 33633 --- [ration.thread-0] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OutboundResponseHandler   : [192.168.53.176]:5701 [baam-auth-connector] [5.1.5] Cannot send response: null to [127.0.0.1]:5701. com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.SplitBrainMergeValidationOp{serviceName='hz:core:clusterService', identityHash=364703456, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=83, invocationTime=1686743035798 (2023-06-14 15:13:55.798), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.tenantcontrol.NoopTenantControl@0}
```

Also there are different types of config for Discovery Mechanisms in hazelcast such as TCP, Multicast, Kubernetes Cloud Discovery. I don't know which one I should use and if my problem has something to do with that.